# Citrix - Accessing "Presentation Server 4" and "XenApp 5" from the same device

Tags: citrix, xenapp

How could one access a very old "Presentation Server 4" farm and a slightly newer "XenApp 5" farm from the same user desktop? Upgrading the "Presentation Server 4" farm is unfortunatley not an option.

Perhaps there's a way to install two versions of the Windows client on the same desktop (thick and a thin cient)? Or perhaps there's a client that's compatible with the two farms (note that the "XenApp 5" is accessed via 2048 bit certs so needs a newish client).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, it should really be asked on StackExchange.com instead, but I'll answer it anyway.

You don't have to rely on configuring the server address in receiver, you can get into your farms using Web Interface as well. I.e. This should work fine if you log into the different farms using your web browser (assuming each farm has their own Web Interface configured). Then you can just click on your apps in the browser and Receiver should launch automatically.